# What is different between start <service> & service <service> start

Tags: service, centos

I'm working with choronos and it suggest to start stop using start/stop command like below

start chronos

stop chronos

But, I'm writing puppet manifest and it only work with service command like below.

service chronos start

service chorines stop

What is different two of them and how could I use service  instead of start/stop ?

FYI, my os is cents

Answer (score 0):

They are **entirely** different commands.

The first are the `start` and `stop` commands (which may not exist on systems not using Upstart).

The latter two are the `service` command with `start` and `stop` arguments.

Comment: If I want to use "service" command instead of "start"/"stop" what do I need to do ?

Comment: To use either `service` or `start`/`stop` you need to be on a system that has those commands. `service` is a RedHat/CentOS standard which was "replaced" by `start`/`stop` in CentOS 6 (with Upstart) and "replaced" again in CentOS 7 (with systemd).

Comment: On CentOS 6 both `service` and `start`/`stop` are available and used (different services use different ones). On CentOS 7 `service` is just a compatibility wrapper around the native systemd tools.